# How to generate a table dynamically and group rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I want to generate data in data table based on JSON response. Following is my JSON response:

```
{
  "alertItems": [
    {
      "id": "PROD-115388",
      "errors": [
       "Original Estimate is null",
       "id is null"          
      ],
      "warnings": [
        "Original Estimate is above threshold",
        "Story points are above threshold",
        "These sub tasks are not defined."
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "PROD-112479",
      "errors": [],
      "warnings": [
        "Original Estimate is above threshold",
        "Story points are above threshold",
        "Estimate is missing for these sub tasks : PROD-112329"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "PROD-108461",
      "errors": [],
      "warnings": [
        "Original Estimate is above threshold",
        "Story points are above threshold",
        "These sub tasks are not defined : Test Case, BA Documentation Task, QA Design and Execute Task, BA/QA/Dev, BA Testing Task, QA Documentation Task, Elaboration"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "numberOfErrors": 0,
  "numberOfWarnings": 10
}
```

I want to generate Table like following: 
[image]

I have array of warnings and errors. I want to generate a row for each warning/error against its Id. How can I do that in jQuery [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables)?

Comment: please check the sample code in this thread it may help you  : https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32107/how-to-load-an-array-of-json-objects-to-datatables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to specify callback function that will transform your data to desired format:

```
const transform = data => 
    data.alertItems
        .map(({id, errors, warnings}) => 
            [...errors.map(error => ({id, type: 'error', reason: error})),
            ...warnings.map(warning => ({id, type: 'warning', reason:warning}))])
        .flat();
```

In order to group your table rows by matching id's in the first column, you may use `rowspan` HTML attribute set from within [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) function (in order to do that, you'll need to ensure that your table rows sorting order is fixed, so that items with the same id will go sequentially regardless of the sorting/filtering).

So, the complete example (with ajax part commented out, since it's not available within live snippet) might look, like:

```js
//original JSON
const srcJSON = {"alertItems":[{"id":"PROD-115388","errors":["Original Estimate is null","id is null"],"warnings":["Original Estimate is above threshold","Story points are above threshold","These sub tasks are not defined"]},{"id":"PROD-112479","errors":[],"warnings":["OriginalEstimateisabovethreshold","Storypointsareabovethreshold","Estimateismissingforthesesubtasks: PROD-112329"]},{"id":"PROD-108461","errors":[],"warnings":["OriginalEstimateisabovethreshold","Storypointsareabovethreshold","Thesesubtasksarenotdefined: TestCase, BADocumentationTask, QADesignandExecuteTask, BA/QA/Dev, BATestingTask, QADocumentationTask, Elaboration"]}],"numberOfErrors":0,"numberOfWarnings":10};

//proper JSON
const transform = data => data.alertItems.map(({id, errors, warnings}) => [...errors.map(error => ({id, type: 'error', reason: error})),...warnings.map(warning => ({id, type: 'warning', reason:warning}))]).flat();

//datatables init
$('table').DataTable({
/*
  ajax: {
    url: //url to API endpoint returning original JSON
    method: //http method (GET, POST, etc)
    dataSrc: transform(data)
  }
*/
  data: transform(srcJSON),     //this one should be dropped once ajax section uncommented
  paging: false,
  orderFixed: [0,'asc'],
  columns: [
    {data: 'id', title: 'Story Id'},
    {data: 'type', title: 'Type'},
    {data: 'reason', title: 'Warning Reason'}
  ],
  //group by first col, using rowspan attribute
  drawCallback: function(){
 //clean up the view
 $('tbody td').attr('rowspan',1).show();
 //grab datatable into variable
 const table = this.api();
 //grab visible, sorted table rows
 const rows = table.rows({search:'applied',order:'current'}).nodes();
 var groupIdTd = null;
 //run through the table rows and set 'rowspan' attribute for matching id's
 $.each(rows, function(idx){
  const rowspan = Number($(groupIdTd).attr('rowspan') || 1);
  idx > 0 && table.cell(groupIdTd).data() == table.cell(this,0).data() ?
  ($(groupIdTd).attr('rowspan', rowspan+1), $(table.cell(this,0).node()).hide()) :
  (groupIdTd = table.cell(this,0).node(), $(groupIdTd).attr('rowspan',1));
 });
  }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.0/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css" />
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.0/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to transform the data before passing it to DataTables using [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option. Another component of the solution is third-party **rowsGroup** extension which allows to group rows with identical data.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'ajax': {
      'url': 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1b72lv',
      'dataSrc': function ( data ) {
         var resultData = [];

         if(data.hasOwnProperty('alertItems')){
            $.each(data.alertItems, function( index, record ) {
               $.each(record.errors, function( index, message ) {
                  resultData.push([ record['id'], 'Error', message ]);
               });

               $.each(record.warnings, function( index, message ) {
                  resultData.push([ record['id'], 'Warning', message ]);
               });
            });
         }

         return resultData;
      }
   },
   'rowsGroup': [0]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/6u4pd9zn/) for code and demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables: ROWSPAN in table body TBODY](https://jsfiddle.net/n4dyc7x3/) for more details on **rowsGroup** extension.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg, I agree, your data transforming solution is more elegant, although I am not sure about setting the `rowspan` attribute.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg, updated the answer to get rid of the separate Ajax call and let DataTables handle it, very good point!